# android multi select options with ok and cancel buttons

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a day select user interace with an ok and cancel buttons. This is basically the same thing that is on the alarm function to pick the days, but I can't seem to find a good example that I can make sense of so I can understand it. Anyone know of a good example? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to basically have a linear layout with a checkbox and two buttons at the bottom of the activity.  The layout would be something like:
  (PS - This is the most basic solution.  You get more control using individual textviews and RelativeLayouts)

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Sunday"/> 
    <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Monday"/>
   <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Tuesday"/>
    <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Wednesday"/>
    <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Thursday"/>
    <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Friday"/>
    <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Saturday"/>
</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
      android:layout_with="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="OK"/>
    <Button
      android:layout_with="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Cancel"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```